# BigQuery ML taking too much time to create model

Tags: google-bigquery, logistic-regression, google-cloud-automl, automl

I am using BigQuery ML to build a classification model using logistic regression. Till 2 months back, Create model used to take 20 mins running time, but suddenly nowadays the exact same historical query with same day can’t able to complete run in 1 hr as well. The main problem that I am able to identify is “preprocess” strep of model building. Does anyone know what could have changed in BigQuery ML  that could lead to this?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, can you provide us the successful and failure job ids ? We will look into the detailed logs and get back to you asap. Meanwhile, you can also email the BigQuery ML team via bqml-feedback@google.com to get more support.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback, can you provide us the successful and failure job ids ? We will look into the detailed logs and get back to you asap. Meanwhile, you can also email the BigQuery ML team via bqml-feedback@google.com to get more support.

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question. Please edit according to "How to Answer". Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.